# Where to buy Ubuntu Desktop certified computers?

Tags: asus, ubuntu-netbook

I am trying to buy a new netbook, the Asus X101CH. I noticed that it's only compatible with Ubuntu Desktop if you buy it pre installed from the manufacturer. I can't find anybody who sells it pre installed, and I'm also wondering if it will work if I download and install it with some modifications? I really want to run Ubuntu on this little machine. Thanks

Comment: AU is not for recommending hardware ;) Plus... let's say I know a store in The Netherlands. How is that going to help you? See http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/

Answer (score 1):

For Refereeing Certified Hardware, visit: [**Ubuntu Certified hardware**](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/).

For Ubuntu Desktop certified hardware: [**Ubuntu Desktop certified hardware**](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/desktop/).
As you mentioned for Asus visit : [Ubuntu Desktop certified hardware Asus](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/desktop/make/Asus/?category=Desktop&category=Laptop).

**Visit [Partners page](http://www.ubuntu.com/partners/find-a-partner/hardware) from which you can get information about partners and certified products and also pre-installed/pre-loaded Ubuntu OS.**

> Canonical partners help to ensure that Ubuntu will always be
>   compatible with the latest hardware and software. And they provide a
>   range of services from implementation support to specialist tools.

[**ASUS and Ubuntu**](http://www.ubuntu.com/partners/asus/) Partners.

> ASUS is a multinational computer manufacturer headquartered in Taipei,
>   Taiwan. They have been working with Canonical to bring great
>   performing notebooks, netbooks and all in one computers to consumers
>   and enterprises.

---

But Remember from https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic,

> This is not the right place for: Shopping and Hardware Recommendations.

*Note: This answer doesn't recommend any hardware such as Asus but only Informative and supportive answer to the question*